# Contour Property

Tags: raspberry-pi, contour, centroid, opencv, python

Suppose I have 5 shapes or contours in an image and I will be getting 5 centroid value from contour property. How can I compare centroid values of 5 shapes. Please help me I am new to opencv python.

Comment: Please help me guys. I am stuck. I want to complete my project soon. Deadline is approaching and I cannot move forward without solving this problem. Please help

Comment: Can you share some images? You could try finding moments instead of centroids and run a comparison among them